# Force matrix_world to be recalculated in Blender

Tags: python, matrix, blender

I'm designing an add-on for blender, that changes the location of certain vertices of an object. Every object in blender has a matrix_world atribute, that holds a matrix that transposes the coordinates of the vertices from the object to the world frame.

```
print(object.matrix_world) # unit matrix (as expected)
object.location += mathutils.Vector((5,0,0))
object.rotation_quaternion *= mathutils.Quaternion((0.0, 1.0, 0.0), math.radians(45))
print(object.matrix_world) # Also unit matrix!?!
```

The above snippet shows that after the translation, you still have the same matrix_world. How can I force blender to recalculate the matrix_world?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should call [`Scene.update`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.update) after changing those values, otherwise Blender won't recalculate `matrix_world` until it's needed [somewhere else]. The reason, according to the ["Gotcha's" section](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/info_gotcha.html) in the API docs, is that this re-calc is an expensive operation, so it's not done right away:

> Sometimes you want to modify values from python and immediately access the updated values, eg:
>
> Once changing the objects [bpy.types.Object.location](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.location) you may want to access its transformation right after from [bpy.types.Object.matrix_world](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world), but this doesn’t work as you might expect.
>
> Consider the calculations that might go into working out the objects final transformation, this includes:
>
> - animation function curves.
> - drivers and their pythons expressions.
> - constraints
> - parent objects and all of their f-curves, constraints etc.
>
> To avoid expensive recalculations every time a property is modified, Blender defers making the actual calculations until they are needed.
>
> However, while the script runs you may want to access the updated values.
>
> This can be done by calling [bpy.types.Scene.update](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.update) after modifying values which recalculates all data that is tagged to be updated.

Comment: Note that this has become `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` in Blender 2.8.

Answer (score 3):

**Calls to `bpy.context.scene.update()` can become expensive when called within a loop**.

If your objects have no complex constraints (e.g. plain or parented), the following can be used to recompute the world matrix after changing object's `.location`, `.rotation_euler\quaternion`, or `.scale`.

```
def update_matrices(obj):
    if obj.parent is None:
        obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_basis

    else:
        obj.matrix_world = obj.parent.matrix_world * \
                           obj.matrix_parent_inverse * \
                           obj.matrix_basis
```

Some notes:

- Immediately after setting object location/rotation/scale the object's `matrix_basis` is updated
- But `matrix_local` (when parented) and `matrix_world` are only updated during `scene.update()`
- When `matrix_world` is manually recomputed (using the code above), `matrix_local` is recomputed as well
- If the object is parented, then its world matrix depends on the parent's world matrix as well as the parent's inverse matrix at the time of creation of the parenting relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this too but needed this value to be updated whilst I imported a large scene with tens of thousands of objects. 
Calling 'scene.update()' became exponentially slower, so I needed to find a way to do this without calling that function.
This is what I came up with:

```
def BuildScaleMatrix(s):
    return Matrix.Scale(s[0],4,(1,0,0)) * Matrix.Scale(s[1],4,(0,1,0)) * Matrix.Scale(s[2],4,(0,0,1))

def BuildRotationMatrixXYZ(r):
    return  Matrix.Rotation(r[2],4,'Z') * Matrix.Rotation(r[1],4,'Y') * Matrix.Rotation(r[0],4,'X')

def BuildMatrix(t,r,s):
    return   Matrix.Translation(t) * BuildRotationMatrixXYZ(r) * BuildScaleMatrix(s)

def UpdateObjectTransform(ob):
    ob.matrix_world = BuildMatrix(ob.location, ob.rotation_euler, ob.scale)
```

This isn't most efficient way to build a matrix (if you know of a better way in blender, please add) and this only works for XYZ order transforms but this avoids exponential slow downs when dealing with large data sets.

Comment: This `matrix_world` computation is not always correct : it does not account for the `parent` transformation for example. It probably gives a value close to `ob.matrix_basis `

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Object.matrix_world is causing it to "freeze" even though you don't do anything to it, eg:

```
m = C.active_object.matrix_world
```

causes the matrix to be stuck. Whenever you want to access the matrix use

```
Object.matrix_world.copy()
```

only if you want to write the matrix, use

```
C.active_object.matrix_world = m
```